# jsp for business layer

Tags: jsp

Why shouldn't we use JSP for business layer?

Is it performance?
Or is it just a good practise?
Ofcourse reusablity is one reason.Other than that is there any killer reason why we should use jsp for business layer?

Answer (score 8):

Several reasons:

1. Reusability: you can't reuse scriptlets.
2. Replaceability: you can't make scriptlets abstract.
3. OO-ability: you can't make use of inheritance/composition.
4. Debuggability: if scriptlet throws an exception halfway, all you get is a blank page.
5. Testability: scriptlets are not unit-testable.
6. Maintainability: per saldo more time is needed to maintain mingled/cluttered code logic.

There are more, but it boils down that scriptlets are a **bad practice**.

You can do fairly a lot at the presentation layer with [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) and [EL](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html). If you comes to a point that it is not possible with either of them and you're forced to grab scriptlets, then the code logic ultimately belongs in a *real* Java class. You can use a [`Servlet`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html) class to control/preprocess/postprocess requests, you can use a [`Filter`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html) class to filter requests, you can use a [`DAO`](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) class to do the database interaction, you can use a [`Javabean`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/javabeans/) class to store/transfer/access data, you can use a `Domain` class for business logic, you can use an `Utility` class for static tools.

Comment: For what is worth, about half a year later I've posted a more detailed answer on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason is separation of concerns. You should make it easy to modify the presentation without affecting the business layer.

Comment: assume that I don't change it frequently

Comment: being creatures of habit its always good to follow the best practices, as they become infused in us

Answer (score 0):

Reusability and Maintainability are some of the huge issue.

Consider the situation below;

1. Imagine you want to create an iPhone
   version of the application, you have
   to port all the business logic to
   the iPhone, now lets have an Eclipse
   RCP frontend for the
   application and a Flash based; then integrate with a Python based system.
2. Because the business logic and the
   presentation are in the same file,
   the creative Web Developer has to
   learn some Java if he is going to
   create the best interface without
   breaking the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making an application that is more than 5 pages, mixing logic and presentation could make your life harder. But here is an unpopular opinion of mine - for small applications (or even medium-ones), with a single developer that 'knows his code', it is OK to use JSPs for buisness logic. It could be jsps placed in an `/action/` folder, that later redirect to the presentation ones, or it could be the same jsps where the request comes from. I have an example for that - in the beginning of my development practice I made a web-based strategy game based almost entirely on self-posting jsps. That was 5 years ago. A few weeks ago I took a look at my codebase, and I could understand everything. So if you are just beginning, and you don't want to start with a big framework that will make your learning curve even steeper, and you don't expect your project to be very large or to become commercial (sidenote: mine became commercial at one point), then feel free to use jsps for business logic, but be adviced that *this is not a good practice in the common case*.