# Java error loading JSP file

Tags: java, jsp

That's the problem.

I developed a web app with NetBeans 7, Tomcat 7 and hsqldb; on my desktop all is Ok.

When I upload my java files (.class and .jsp) to my site and try to load a jsp page which imports a class contained in a package (class FunzioniSessione in package it.swlab.util), I get the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 


An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. it.swlab.util.FunzioniSessione resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
FunzioniSessione cannot be resolved to a type
4: <%
5: synchronized(this)
6: {
7: FunzioniSessione funzioniSessione = new FunzioniSessione();
8: String percorso = config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
9: funzioniSessione.inizializza(session,request,response,percorso,"infocar");
10: boolean connesso = session.getAttribute("utenteConnesso") != null;

An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
FunzioniSessione cannot be resolved to a type
4: <%
5: synchronized(this)
6: {
7: FunzioniSessione funzioniSessione = new FunzioniSessione();
8: String percorso = config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
9: funzioniSessione.inizializza(session,request,response,percorso,"infocar");
10: boolean connesso = session.getAttribute("utenteConnesso") != null;

Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:93)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:451)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:328)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:307)
 org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
 org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:565)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:309)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5.33 logs.
```

Due to some answers, I add some more information:
- the package containing the class FunzioniSessione (named funzioniComuni.jar) is in the WEB-INF\lib folder
- I can't look at the logs as the note in the stacktrace suggests, because I have no access to the logs folder of my provider's Tomcat server
- the directive for the import is
  <%@page import="it.swlab.util.FunzioniSessione"%>
  I tried also with a ";" at the end (<%@page import="it.swlab.util.FunzioniSessione;"%>) but with no success

Thanks to who answered, I wait for new suggestions.

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the logs as the note in your stacktrace sugests? "note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5.33 logs"

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1858463/74057 . See if those suggestions help

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the .java or the .jar file that contains the FunzioniSessione class on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your page directive import in the jsp? As in:

<%@page import="javapackage.FunzioniSessione "%>

Just because eclipse knows where it is Tomcat won't without this.

The import doesn't use ";", so don't use it.

How did you do your build and deploy, with ANT?  Are you sure the class files are being generated? and the war has to be deployed properly as well.  We need more information here.

This is something simple, so let us know exactly what steps you took to build and deploy the application as I believe that is where the problem is.

HTH,

James

Answer (score 0):

> *The package containing the class FunzioniSessione is in the WEB-INF\lib folder.*

The `/WEB-INF/lib` folder is for JAR files. classes should go in `/WEB-INF/classes` folder. In this particular case, you must have a `/WEB-INF/classes/it/swlab/util/FunzioniSessione.class` file.