# JSP - Package not found

Tags: jsp, tomcat, tomcat6

I just installed tomcat 6 on my server with Apache.

My jsp file return the following error:

> Only a type can be imported. x.y.Z resolves to a package

In the source file, I have the following line:

> <%@ page language="java" import="x.y.Z" %>

I have checked on the Internet, and from what I understood, Tomcat can not find my class Z
However, I have my Z.class file in /website/WEB-INF/classes/x/y/Z.class

In /etc/tomcat6/Catalina/www.mydomain.com/, I have in the ROOT.xml file:

> < Context path="/website/" antiResourceLocking="false" />

The file /etc/tomcat6/server.xml contains:

> <Host name="www.mydomain.com" appBase="/home/user/www/" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
>       <Context path="/" docBase="./" debug="1" reloadable="true"/>
>       <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="/var/log/tomcat6"  prefix="tomcat_access_" suffix=".log" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
>   </Host>

(/home/user/www/website/ is where my jsp files are stored)

I have tried to define a servlet in my web.xml file in WEB-INF but it didn't help.
I have tried to move WEB-INF in / but it did not solve anything.

Any idea about why my Tomcat can't find my class?

Thanks for your help : )

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package

Comment: I have already read it, and read it again. I don't see how this thread can solve my problem. The structure of my app looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually solved my problem.

The architecture of the WEB-INF was ok, but it was not properly placed.
I wrote an article about it with my configuration [here](http://www.neumino.com/blog/2011/10/12/tomcat-apache-and-mod_jk/)