# Spring JSP - Only type can be imported

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven

How do I set the location of the Maven library files to be placed in WAR. Following is the actual problem.
I wrote the following import Statement in the start

```
<%@page import="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext"%>
<%@page import="org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext"%>
```

I'm getting the follwoing error.

**An error occurred at line: 8 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext resolves to a package**

**An error occurred at line: 9 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext resolves to a package**

What does that mean?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package

Comment: @Mansuro its not duplicate. That doesn't use spring and i have removed other errors as specified in that question's solution. Only those spring dependancy is creating problem. Can you solve this....?

Comment: Well, it seems to me like it's the same error, the packages were not found in the classpath

Comment: I'm using Maven. Spring is maven dependency. Other dependancies where normal class files. I've set the build path for that to classes folder. Is there a way to set path for maven dependency. I'm using eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra semicolon after the class name in your import attribute, maybe that is simply the reason for the error. The error message would be absolutely misleading in that case.