# Glassfish and Tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, netbeans, glassfish

I write a web service program on *NetBeans*. it's work without any problem with *GlassFish* server but when I want to run by *Tomcat 7.x.x* I received this error:

```
Type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ConvertDateTimeHandler resolves to a package

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:97)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 3):

The in the exception message mentioned class is part of JSF.

Glassfish is a full fledged Java EE application server and ships with JSP, Servlet, EL, JSF, JPA, EJB, JAX-RS and all that other fancy Java EE stuff bundled. Tomcat, on the other hand, is a barebones servletcontainer which ships with only JSP, Servlet and EL. Tomcat does not ship with JSF bundled.

You need to either install JSF in Tomcat, or to prodive JSF yourself along with the webapp. Glassfish ships with the JSF reference implementation [Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net). If you download it, you'll find a `javax.faces.jar` file in the zip file. If you copy this into the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp, rebuild the webapp and redeploy to Tomcat, then this problem should disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you are missing some JAR files in your classpath, read the following similar questions:

http://anilsaldhana.blogspot.de/2009/07/tomcat-error-only-type-can-be-imported.html

[Java error: Only a type can be imported. XYZ resolves to a package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1858463/395659)

http://www.bonitasoft.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=3381