# Can Netbeans Deploy to a remote tomcat server when my localhost is using glassfish?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, netbeans, deployment, glassfish

I'm using NetBeans for creating and testing a web application, primarily servlets and JSPs. Though at the moment it's just the random tinkering or someone who claims not to like web-development, I've been looking at some hosting options, in case it turns into something worth putting out (always nice to add something to the resume).

I'm thinking that when I do cave in, that Arvixe looks ideal (cheap, dev-friendly, supports JSP).

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094125/glassfish-and-tomcat) I should mention that the only things I'm currently using are standard servlets, JSP, and EL.

Currently my project is using Glassfish as a server during localhost testing, but most hosts (including Arvixe) are using Apache Tomcat, so my question is this:

How difficult will it be to deploy (port?) an application developed, and tested, with Glassfish to a remote machine running Tomcat?
Should I install Tomcat and swap over (within netbeans) before trying it, or is it trivially easy?

Forgive me my lack of knowledge on the subject, I'm not very experienced with web development.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't. Not only it needs to run on the same machine as netbeans, but it needs to be able to start-stop-restart it.

I am really sorry about this, too.