# HTTP Status 500 on Tomcat / Windows 7

Tags: jsp, tomcat, tomcat7

I'm constantly getting error **HTTP Status 500** for all JSP pages which uses external Java class defined outside JSP pages. Here are the codes

*index.jsp*

```
<%@page import="mypack.sou" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

<% 
sou o=new sou();
int r=o.hi();
out.println(r);
%>
</body>
</html>
```

*sou.java* under package *mypack*

```
package mypack;
public class sou {
public int hi()
 {
    return 0;
 }
}
```

---

The error:

> type Exception report
>
> "message Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line:
>   14 in the generated java file Only a type can be imported. mypack.sou
>   resolves to a package An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file:
>   /web/index.jsp sou cannot be resolved to a type 15:
>
> ## Hello
>   World!
>
> 16: 17: <% 18: sou o=new sou(); 19: int r=o.hi(); 20:
>   out.println(r); 21: %> An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file:
>   /web/index.jsp sou cannot be resolved to a type 15:
>
> ## Hello
>   World!
>
> 16: 17: <% 18: sou o=new sou(); 19: int r=o.hi(); 20:
>   out.println(r); 21: %> Stacktrace:
>
> description The server encountered an internal error (Unable to
>   compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated
>   java file Only a type can be imported. mypack.sou resolves to a
>   package An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file: /web/index.jsp
>   sou cannot be resolved to a type 15:
>
> ## Hello World!
>
> 16: 17: <%
>   18: sou o=new sou(); 19: int r=o.hi(); 20: out.println(r); 21: %> An
>   error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file: /web/index.jsp sou cannot
>   be resolved to a type 15:
>
> ## Hello World!
>
> 16: 17: <% 18: sou
>   o=new sou(); 19: int r=o.hi(); 20: out.println(r); 21: %> Stacktrace:)
>   that prevented it from fulfilling this request."

---

## Directory structure

- webapps
  |*app

  |*_ index.jsp
  |_ *WEB-INF

  ......|*_ classes
  .............|**_** mypack
  ....................|_sou.class, test.war, mypack.jar

---

**System Info:** Win 7 Ultimate X64, Apache Tomcat 7.0.29
java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode, sharing)
Tomcat directory has full permission !

---

I had to move to GlassFish, where the same code works ! But the problem still exist with Tomcat

Comment: The question is damn long, I know. But this should not be referred to CODEREVIEW as it's not a problem related to code I believe. **Before -1 voting write your reasons so I can rectify myself from similar error in future** !

Comment: What is the exact output you get on browser?

Comment: I've written output on the error section

Comment: you getting that Hello World! part four times?

Comment: Nope, they are being shown in the error section while showing the code

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of your problem, but just for the sake of clarity you should start by respecting the convention that class names should begin by a captial letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a ";" to your import statement.

modify like this:

```
<%@page import="mypack.sou;" %>
<!DOCTYPE html> //Remove content type
```

May be this looks like a weird answer, but see this reference 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1858635/586836

EDIT:

Otherwise:
Try compiling that java file to a class manually and then put that in the classes directory and check.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 
`mypack.sou` instead of  `sou` ;
You have to use the fully-qualified class name inside JSPs, since all JSPs are turned into plain old Java servlet code by the Container. 
or you can import your package instead :

```
<%@ page import=”mypack.*” %>
```

Comment: Tried, but no effect. I think the code has no error, the problem is with Win 7 or Tomcat !