# Trouble importing classes to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea

In it's wisdom [jspc](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jspc/jspc-maven-plugin/) told me the following about one of my `JSP`s

```
[ERROR] MyClassName cannot be resolved to a type
```

Indeed it was not there.. Hmm .. Lets include it!

```
<%@ page import="com.a.b.c.MyClassName"%>
```

Ok, now `jspc` says

```
[ERROR] Only a type can be imported. com.a.b.c.MyClassName resolves to a package
```

That's simply is not true, but ok, lets try wildcarding it

```
<%@ page import="com.a.b.c.*"%>
```

`jspc` comes back with original error of

```
[ERROR] MyClassName cannot be resolved to a type
```

Any ideas?

---

### UPDATE

Confirmed: issue is isolated to the build time. At run time, assuming all imports are done as shown above, everything works.

Comment: `Settings` | `Compiler` | `Validation`, **Validate on build** is enabled with **Jasper** option turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my understanding `com.a.b.c.MyClassName` is in a Class Loader not accessible by the JSP.

This can happen if you have multiple web applications and the JSP is in a web app and the class in another.

To test that simply put the class in the app server global classpath.

Comment: When my project is compiled `.class` files are placed into `target/project_name/classes`. Where in JSP (or elsewhere) can i add them to `classpath`?

Comment: So they are both in the same web application (WAR)? In any case you can also try to use a Class.forName(com.a.b.c.MyClassName) in the JSP and see if the class can be loaded from the JSP or what exception the class loader returns. This can exclude or confirm a class loader issue.

Comment: Tony, please see update above. It seems that issue is isolated to the build time. At runtime, once imports are in place things work. Could my project set up be messed up somehow?

Comment: So it seems very likely a class loader issue due to the "classpath" view of the JSP compiler at build time. I saw that in jspc usage page they say to use it in conjunction with the [maven-war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html). Have you double checked the class path configuration of that plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JSP config has no link to the JAR/resource of the class.

Some links that could help :

[The same problem as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package)

[A JAR include problem leading to the same error](http://www.bonitasoft.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=3381)

[A Tomcat config problem leading... to the same](http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=10513&start=0&postdays=0&postorder=asc&highlight=)

I hope these links were useful.

Comment: I looked at the first link (before posting) and solution did not help

Comment: Okay, and the others ? Did help something ?