# How is JSPC called?

Tags: java, jsp, maven, pom.xml

Given:

1. Upon running `mvn clean install` JSP compiler `jspc` reports issues
2. Issues are confirmed real. When deploying code as is (without fixing anything) JSP is broken at runtime
3. Upon fixing the issues and deploying the application, issues go away

Problem: Fix is not recognized by JSPC

### How is JSPC called?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.jspc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includeInProject>false</includeInProject>
                <sources>
                    <directory>${basedir}/myapp/src/main/webapp/</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.jsp</include>
                    </includes>
                </sources>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.jspc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jspc-compiler-tomcat6</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0-alpha-3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

### What errors are reported?

```
[ERROR] MyClass cannot be resolved to a type
```

### More details about the problem:

Similar question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692043/trouble-importing-classes-to-jsp)

**It seems like a classpath problem, but where in pom can it be set please?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding

```
<workingDirectory>${basedir}/myapp/target/classes</workingDirectory>
```

inside `<configuration>` tags