# Only a type can be imported. ABC resolves to a package

Tags: java, jsp

(I've read other questions on this topic, but none of them have helped)

Okay, I'm trying to import a Java class into my JSP file, but Tomcat gives me the error:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> ```
> An error occurred at line: [16] in the generated java file: [I:\path\to\index_jsp.java]
> Only a type can be imported. org.runas.XKCDUtils resolves to a package
>
> An error occurred at line: 7 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
> XKCDUtils cannot be resolved
> ```

```
4:  String data = null;
5:  int finalComic = 1;
6:  int comicNo = 1;
7:  finalComic = XKCDUtils.getFinalComic();
8: 
9:  if (request.getParameter("page") != null)
10:         comicNo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
```

The import statement in my JSP file is:

```
<%@page import="java.io.*, java.net.*, org.runas.XKCDUtils" %>
```

The relevant section of my directory structure is:

```
webapps
`-ROOT
 `-index.jsp
 |-WEB-INF
  `-web.xml
  |-classes
   `-org
    `-runas
     `-XKCDUtils.class
```

I'm confused because `org.runas.XKCDUtils resolves to a package`, and yet it is clearly a class file, in what I believe is the correct directory.

Help, please!

(And don't chastise me for using scriptlets, I'm trying to clean them up!)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package). Split the import into 3 separate ones and possibly add a semi-colon at the last one.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, this is weird.
I split the import into three imports,

```
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@page import="org.runas.XKCDUtils" %>
```

and it magically decided to work. Then when I changed the imports back,

```
<%@page import="java.io.*, java.net.*, org.runas.XKCDUtils" %>
```

it magically decided to keep working.

Maybe it had something to do with restarting Tomcat? Well, it works now, anyway.

Comment: _Maybe it had something to do with restarting Tomcat?_ - Pretty much: after installing a library, you need to restart Tomcat for loading it. So apparently, the answer to your question is: restart Tomcat. Feel free to add the new answer and select it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem; resolved by stopping the server (Tomcat in my case) and rebuilding the project.

Comment: Restarting the server fixed the problem for me too.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what exactly caused the error, but I changed

```
<%@page import="java.io.*, java.net.*, org.runas.XKCDUtils" %>
```

to

```
<%@page import="java.io.*, java.net.*, org.runas.*" %>
```

and it worked. My interpretation of the error is that for some reason Tomcat thinks XKCDUtils is a package, not a class in the package. Importing with * then makes it unambiguous that it's importing classes.