# Error in JSON Array create using JSP

Tags: json, jsp

I am trying to create a JSON Array using the following code; I have downloaded gson-2.2.4.jar and extracted the com directory in the same location where my JSP file resides

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" import="java.sql.* " %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %> 
<%@page import="com.google.gson.JSONObject"%>
<%

try {
String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/CATCHINFO";
String username = "postgres";
String password = "123";
String myDataField = null;
String category = null;
String myQuery = "SELECT * FROM cruce order by cruce_no";
Connection myConnection = null;
PreparedStatement myPreparedStatement = null;
ResultSet myResultSet = null;
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
myPreparedStatement = myConnection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
myResultSet = myPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

while(myResultSet.next()){

category = myResultSet.getString("cruce_no");
json.put("city", category);
out.print(category);
}
}
catch(Exception e){
out.print(e);
}

%>"
```

But I am getting errors:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 16 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.google.gson.JSONObject resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 21 in the jsp file: /loadCruceNo.jsp
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
An error occurred at line: 21 in the jsp file: /loadCruceNo.jsp
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound right that you "extracted the com directory in the same location where my JSP file resides".

The jar should either be in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your web application or if you decide to unpack all the classes (as you have the described) the com directory should be in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory.

Comment: Danny I am working on UBUNTU not in windows. In windows we can just need to append jar with classpath, but in  Linux we can not. I put it in WEB-INF/classes directory as you mentioned, but not working.

Comment: I have not mentioned Windows in any way. In a web application you can add jars to your WEB-INF/lib directory and you do not need to specify them elsewhere. By not working, do you mean you still get the same error?

Comment: If that is not the only problem, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package among the answers it is suggested to add a semicolon to the last import line.

Comment: Semi column added still no change

Comment: Have you tried by adding the jar to the lib folder?

Comment: Try to restart your server as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962709/only-a-type-can-be-imported-abc-resolves-to-a-package

Comment: Ty Danny, but its hell with working in linux. For windows it will work fine. I have done this before.