# What is the proper project structure? Only a type can be imported (Java Web)

Tags: java, jsp, web, server-side

I get the error:

```
Only a type can be imported. com.user.MyClass resolves to a package
```

Of course this is a class in the package user.

I am wondering about project structure. I am unsure what WEB-INF is supposed to hold, or where the files should go in general.

Currently, I have my business logic .java in ROOT>src
I have a folder for CSS, JSP, JavaScript in WebContent, next to WEB-INF and META-INF.

I think the problem is that the JSP is not finding MyClass properly.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962709/only-a-type-can-be-imported-abc-resolves-to-a-package

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the compiled java code goes to `/WEB-INF/classes/*` and the dependent library in `/WEB-INF/lib/`

see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1830/abxft/index.html)

If you are using Eclipse check teh project properties

`Properties --> Deployment Assembly`

to know the location of the compiled java code.