# JSP - Only a type can be imported. Name.pacakge.class resolves to a package but the class is there

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web-deployment

I'm receiving this error while trying to deploy a webapp via tomcat 7.

The jsp file name `analysis.jsp` and this is the error:

```
Apr 05, 2017 3:05:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [analyserServlet] in web application [/MWE] threw load() exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [26] in the generated java file: [/usr/share/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/MWE/org/apache/jsp/analysis_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. mila.HMM.MorphMult2TaggerFormat resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [27] in the generated java file: [/usr/share/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/MWE/org/apache/jsp/analysis_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. mila.HMM.HMM2Morph resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [28] in the generated java file: [/usr/share/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/MWE/org/apache/jsp/analysis_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. mila.mw.PostProcessor1 resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [29] in the generated java file: [/usr/share/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/MWE/org/apache/jsp/analysis_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. mila.mw.MWXMLTokenizer resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /analysis.jsp
mila.mw.MWXMLTokenizer cannot be resolved to a type
33: String tokenizeAndAnalyze(String rawText) throws Exception {
34:     StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
35:     try (InputStream ins = new ByteArrayInputStream(rawText.getBytes("UTF-8"))) {
36:         new mila.mw.MWXMLTokenizer().tokenizeAndAnalyze(ins, new PrintWriter(sw));
37:     }
38:     StringWriter ppSW = new StringWriter();
39:     try (InputStream ins = new ByteArrayInputStream(sw.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"))) {


An error occurred at line: 40 in the jsp file: /analysis.jsp
mila.mw.PostProcessor1 cannot be resolved to a type
37:     }
38:     StringWriter ppSW = new StringWriter();
39:     try (InputStream ins = new ByteArrayInputStream(sw.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"))) {
40:         new mila.mw.PostProcessor1().process(ins,  new PrintWriter(ppSW));
41:     }
42:     return ppSW.toString();
43: }


An error occurred at line: 46 in the jsp file: /analysis.jsp
mila.HMM.MorphMult2TaggerFormat cannot be resolved to a type
43: }
44: 
45: String runTagger(String xmlAnalyzed, String _tempDirectoryPath) throws Exception {
46:     final String taggerFormat = new mila.HMM.MorphMult2TaggerFormat()
47:                             .myWEBMorp2Tagger(xmlAnalyzed, _tempDirectoryPath);
48:     final String roydir = "/data/tagger/royTagger/";
49:     final String probabilityDir = "/data/tagger/taggerLearningOutputFile/";


An error occurred at line: 60 in the jsp file: /analysis.jsp
mila.HMM.HMM2Morph cannot be resolved to a type
57:     
58:     final String xmlTaggedFilename = _tempDirectoryPath + "/tagged.xml";
59:     PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(xmlTaggedFilename);
60:     new mila.HMM.HMM2Morph().process(xmlAnalyzed, taggedFilename, pw);
61:     return xmlTaggedFilename;    
62: }
63: 


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:494)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5610)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1260)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:2002)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the import part from the jsp:

```
<%@ page language = "java"
    import = "java.lang.StringBuilder"
    import = "java.io.StringWriter"
    import = "java.io.PrintWriter"
    import = "java.io.ByteArrayInputStream"
    import = "java.io.IOException"
    import = "java.io.File"
    import = "java.io.BufferedReader"
    import = "java.io.InputStreamReader"
    import = "java.io.InputStream"
    import = "java.nio.file.Files"
    import = "java.nio.file.Paths"
    import = "java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption"
    import = "mila.HMM.MorphMult2TaggerFormat"
    import = "mila.HMM.HMM2Morph"
    import = "mila.mw.PostProcessor1"
    import = "mila.mw.MWXMLTokenizer"
%>
```

Under the `WEB-INF/lib` folder I have a JAR named `morphAnalyzer.jar` which is basically the project and it contains all the classes needed including the ones that cause this error.
Here is a partial vim look into the JAR

```
mila/
mila/HMM/
mila/HMM/HMM2Morph.class
mila/HMM/MorphMult2TaggerFormat.class
...
mila/mw/MWXMLMorphAnalyzer.class
mila/mw/MWXMLTokenizer.class
mila/mw/PostProcessor1.class
...
```

As you can see the jar does include all the classes I need but for some reason the jsp file doesn't recognize them as classes.

P.S there is no other package with classes named the same (i.e all classes names are unique throughout the whole project)

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Answers for a similar problem suggested to restart Tomcat, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962709/only-a-type-can-be-imported-abc-resolves-to-a-package

Comment: I tried it. Un-deployed the service, restarted the tomcat, tried to re-deploy and got the same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `morphAnalyzer.jar` in class path of you application

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but how exactly do I do that? this JAR is basically my whole application.

Comment: If you are building desktop app. than your project should be compressed to jar. for web app it should be compressed to .war. And in this war under WEB-INF/lib folder other libraries your app refers should reside . I eclipse you can configure the path for these jar files such that they will be bundled during generation of war file and recognized during compile time

Comment: I'm working on a remote Linux workstation (my PC is windows) and the application is aimed for internet. What I do is creating a jar file (`morphAnalayzer.jar`) exporting it with eclipse (with the referred libraries bundled with it together) and put it inside the `WEB-INF\lib` folder (via SSH to the workstation), and then simply try to deploy it from the tomcat manager (on my PC) by directing it to the folder. I can generate a `.war` file from the whole thing and upload it with the tomcat manager from home, will that have the same effect?

Comment: After you upload jar file using SSH . don't deploy in tomcat manager . simply restart server . if you deploy without creating war . you will loose changes you made by uploading using SSH

Comment: Hey sorry for late reply there was a holiday of 2 weeks here. I didn't understand exactly what you mean - The service is currently un-deployed completely. Should I re-deploy it? Create a WAR file of it on my windows workstation and deploy said file?

Answer (score 0):

classes are to be comma separated in the import attribute.

Like the below:

import ="mila.HMM.MorphMult2TaggerFormat, mila.HMM.HMM2Morph, mila.mw.PostProcessor1 ,mila.mw.MWXMLTokenizer"

Comment: So I should change all imports to look like `import = "class1, class2, class3, ... "`?

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately, and I tried restarting the tomcat as well.

Comment: Have you added "mila.HMM.MorphMult2TaggerFormat, mila.HMM.HMM2Morph, mila.mw.PostProcessor1 ,mila.mw.MWXMLTokenizer" in first of your import statement ? If NO, Add those in fist.

Comment: No they are at the end of it. What difference does that make though? (Will try replacing them now).

Comment: AND delete your work directory in tomcat before restarting

Comment: I put them first (and then all the `java.somthing` in the same line), un-deployed the service, restarted the tomcat and then re-deployed it again but it didn't work. By deleting the work directory do you mean the original directory of the whole app(my local one not the one under `/usr/shar/tomcat/...`)? Or just un-deploying?

Comment: Delete  ONLY  the work folder which resides in the  tomcat directory and restart the tomcat

Comment: If you're referring to `/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/MWE` (which is the context name I gave it) then I have deleted it.

Comment: NO. Are you using Linux server?

Comment: Yes, a remote linux work station. (I'm working from home now on my PC and using SSH to do stuff there)

Comment: Do you have anyone from like the following folders?                                         /usr/..../tomcat/work/  or    /opt/.../tomcat/work/

Comment: Yes, it includes a single dir `Catalina\localhost` which includes the rest of the webapps (MWE is not there).

Comment: Stop the tomcat and Delete the work directory and then start the tomcat.

Comment: Are you sure? Won't that harm the rest of the webapps? MWE isn't there anyway. Also, simply `sudo rm -r /usr/share/tomcat/work`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't harm anything .Go ahead. Go to /usr/share/tomcat and sudo rm -r work

Comment: Still getting the same error... The tomcat manager's error is `FAIL - Encountered exception javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method check` and in the log the error is the same as before

Comment: Did you follow this ? 
Stop the tomcat and Delete the work directory and then start the tomcat.

Comment: Yes. I un-deployed, stopped the tomcat, deleted the work directory, started the tomcat and tried to deploy the app again via the tomcat manager.

Comment: Could it be that in the tomcat manager I refer it to the whole directory and not creating a WAR file out of it and referring it to the WAR file? I'm using the "Deploy directory or WAR file located on server" and directing it to a directory located at `/data/webapps`

Comment: if you have privileges , try to restart your linux server might be outofmemory issue.

Comment: I don't have these privileges but I will open a request (might take a day or 2 though)

Comment: Do you have a dev setup of your local machine?