# JSP Google API Import error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

My JSP import statement:

```
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataStoreService" %>
```

Error:
Only a type can be imported. com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataStoreService resolves to a package

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have misspelled com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataStoreService

It should be com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService

Note the lowercase 's' in 'Datastore'

If you fix this does it now work?

Comment: This may also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package