# Only a type can be imported. com.journaldev.model.Employee resolves to a package

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

index22.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
  <%@ page import="com.journaldev.model.Employee" %>
<%@ page import="com.journaldev.model.Person" %>
<%@ page import="com.journaldev.model.Address" %>
```

when i am accessing index22.jsp on browser getting the following error:

```
Jul 12, 2015 8:53:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/JSTL] threw exception [Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\piyush\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\JSTL\org\apache\jsp\index22_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.journaldev.model.Employee resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [16] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\piyush\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\JSTL\org\apache\jsp\index22_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.journaldev.model.Person resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [17] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\piyush\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\JSTL\org\apache\jsp\index22_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.journaldev.model.Address resolves to a package

Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\piyush\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\JSTL\org\apache\jsp\index22_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.journaldev.model.Employee resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [16] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\piyush\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\JSTL\org\apache\jsp\index22_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.journaldev.model.Person resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [17] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\piyush\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\JSTL\org\apache\jsp\index22_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.journaldev.model.Address resolves to a package

Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:485)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have also included some JSTL jars and using Tomcat7v

```
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
taglibs-standard-compat-1.2.5.jar
taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
taglibs-standard-jstlel-1.2.5.jar
taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar
```

I guess getting this error because of JSTL I have included but not confirmed.
any idea about the error I am getting?

Employee.java

```
package com.journaldev.model;

public class Employee implements Person {

    private String name;
    private int id;
    private Address address;

    public Employee() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String nm) {
        this.name = nm;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "ID="+id+",Name="+name+",Address="+address;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post full code for `com.journaldev.model.Employee`? Also is it a package or class ?

Comment: @Amit included Employee.java

Comment: You class looks fine. Make sure, Employee.class is deployed under directory **com/journaldev/model** and not **com/journaldev/model/Employee**

Comment: similar issue - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package)

Comment: @Amit I've checked the link the error was of because semicolon (;) was missing and gone through other comments also but doesn't seems enough to solve my problem.

Comment: @BalusC new to java thats why did not know these things. i'll get back to you once resolve this fatal.

Comment: @BalusC added JSTL jars they were missing still getting the same fatal.no idea how to remove it??

Comment: I don think so its a problem other things are working fine.

Comment: thanks @BalusC the problem nay be because of the fatal I created new dynamic web project now its working properly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error was because of exclamation sign on project. I created new web dynamic project and it was running smoothly.

[image]