# Connecting a mysql database to a jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat

I have written out my database and it works (on MySql) and created my own jsp program but when I tried to test the connection between the database and the files i get this error

> HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file:
>   [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\work\Catalina\localhost_\org\apache\jsp\bulletinboard1_1\intermediateLogin_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported. com.bulletinboard.dao.AdminDAOImpl
>   resolves to a package

and when I tried to see if it even connects through the following scriplet i got this error

```
<% 
try {
            String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://host/db_ads";
            Connection connection = null; 
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "noor");
            if(!connection.isClosed())
                 out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
            connection.close();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            out.println("Unable to connect to database"+ex);
        }   
%>
```

I watch tutorials on how to install the driver and all they seemed to do is copy the jar file (mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar) in the lib folder of tomcat.

What am I missing ?

Comment: it seems you are trying to import a package instead of a class "Only a type can be imported. com.bulletinboard.dao.AdminDAOImpl resolves to a package"

Answer (score 0):

At the top:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*
                javax.sql.*"%>
```

or (as pleases)

```
<%@page
   import="java.sql.*"
   import="javax.sql.*"%>
```

1. `.newInstance()` is not needed
2. As of JDBC4 `Class.forName` is not be needed (must be checked)
3. The mysql jar must be added to WEB-INF/lib/

You could also have a servlet preparing all data put them in request attributes and forward to the jsp.
That means you can compile comfortably in the IDE, remove clutter from the jasp. Do things like using a connection pool. Examples in the net.

Answer (score 0):

In the last import add a ";" by copying other code examples. I think the standard line ending that is required.

So

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.bulletinboard.dao.AdminDAOImpl" %>
```

Became

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.bulletinboard.dao.AdminDAOImpl;" %>
```

And check the right [structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1858532/5193194)

Another advise Scriptlets are a [bad practice](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200603/Journal200603.jsp#a5) use a servlet.

Comment: I checked the structure is fine, and putting a ; at the end didn't help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported jar library for below error message:

> com.bulletinboard.dao.AdminDAOImpl

try to remove above imported class or add the jar file for the above class.