# JSP compilation error when using JSONObject

Tags: java, jsp

I created a JSP file with following imports:

```
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.JSONObject" %>
```

This works fine on one system. However, when I copied the file to another system I got the following error:

> Only a type can be imported. org.json.JSONObject resolves to a package

Same version of Java and Tomcat are installed on both the systems. Any idea?

Comment: check your classpath to see if  `json.jar` exists

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis can you please point out the original question? I have gone through them and none of these answers my question.

Comment: Refresh this page. The link will be at the top of your post. If that doesn't solve your issue, please edit your question with your attempt at that solution and what happened. People can then vote to reopen if it makes sense.

Comment: @RafikBELDI Are you refering to classpath parameter in web.xml for JSP compiler? I did not change that in either of the systems. As I said, Tomcat version/configuration etc are identical.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think you are in hurry to mark it duplicate. That question I have read and it is different from my case. I clearly said that in my case the same file runs on one system with identical Tomcat configuration.

Comment: I don't see that any of that is relevant. Ignore the question asked and look at the [answer(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1858635/438154).