# Only a type can be imported. org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse resolves to a package

Tags: java, jsp, types, compiler-errors, package

Folks below is my JSP, I am not able to deploy this on Tomcat.

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <%@ page import = "org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse" %>
  <%@ page import ="org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList" %>
  <%@ page import = "java.util.Iterator" %>
  <%@ page import = "org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocument" %>
  <%@ page import = "org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.FacetField" %>
  <%@ page import = "org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.FacetField.Count" %>
  <%@ page import = "java.util.List" %>
  <%@ page import = "com.google.gson.Gson" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Search Component</h1>
<%! public QueryResponse QryRspnsMain; %>
        <div>
          <form id="formsearch" name="formsearch" method="post"   action="/SearchBoxcComp/hello">
          <span><input name="searchWord" class="editbox_search"   id="editbox_search" maxlength="120" value="" type="text"  style="width:180px; height:20px"/></span>
            <input name="button_search" value="search" type="submit" name="submit"/>
            <div class="clr"></div>
            <%
            if(request.getParameter("submit") != null){
            QueryResponse QryRspnsMain =    (QueryResponse)request.getAttribute("SearchResult");
            Gson gson= new Gson();
            SolrDocumentList results = QryRspnsMain.getResults();
            // Get the Json Object 
            //*************String Jresponse= gson.toJson(results);

            Iterator<SolrDocument> litr = results.iterator();
            String res = gson.toJson(results);
                for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
                    out.print("<li>" + res);
                }
             }
            %>
          </form>
          <div>
          <%
          if(request.getParameter("submit") != null){
              QueryResponse QryRspnsMain = (QueryResponse)request.getAttribute("SearchResult");
                Gson gson= new Gson();
                SolrDocumentList results = QryRspnsMain.getResults();
                List<FacetField> facetList = QryRspnsMain.getFacetFields();
                Iterator<FacetField> itr = facetList.iterator();
                while(itr.hasNext()) {
                    FacetField facetField = itr.next();
                    List<Count> facvalue = facetField.getValues();
                    for(int i=0; i<facvalue.size(); i++){
                         System.out.println(facvalue.get(i));
                         out.print("<li><a href= \"/SearchBoxcComp/FacetServlet?facetFiled=\"" + facvalue.get(i) + "&catlevel=" + facetField.getName());
                         }
                }
          }
           %>
                 </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

When i deploy i get below error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> ---
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file Only a type
>   can be imported. org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse
>   resolves to a package
>
> An error occurred at line: 9 in the generated java file Only a type
>   can be imported. org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.FacetField
>   resolves to a package
>
> An error occurred at line: 19 in the jsp file: /SearchBoxNew.jsp
>   QueryResponse cannot be resolved to a type

Thanks in advance for the suggestion :)

Comment: Check if your classess, i.e org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse and org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.FacetField are on classpath.

Comment: kindly provide classes from where it's incoming, if you have use that class as a external then provide sufficient jar file for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java error: Only a type can be imported. XYZ resolves to a package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package)

Comment: All the jar files are added to classpath. When i use the same logic in simple java program its executing without any error.

Comment: then please, provide servlet-api.jar file into tomcat's library.

Comment: Sorry but how to do it..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it seems that you are trying to import something which is not a class.

If your QueryResponse is a class, you should import it like this:

```
<%@page import="org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse"%>
```

If it is a package and you want to import everything in the package you should do like this:

```
<%@page import="org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.* "%>
```

If you are using maven - check that you have [apropriate dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.solr) in you **pom** file.

Comment: I corrected this.. But still no progress.. And i am not using maven