# HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP Java8, Tomcat8.5

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a main `jsp` file which makes use of `java` class in the `boxers` package. But when I try to run `jsp`, the following error occures:
`HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:in the jsp file: /web/date_info.jsp boxers.B cannot be resolved to a type`.

date_info.jsp

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><%= boxers.B.voice()%></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

B class:

```
 package boxers;


public class B {
    public static String voice()
    {
        return "HELLO";
    }
}
```

I've read the conflict between versions can cause this; my Java version is 8, Tomcat 8.5..

I've looked into `webapps/my_app/build/web/WEB-INF/classes/boxers` folder and there is a `B.class` file...

EDIT: I wonder if those who downvote at least know the answer to the question.

Comment: try importing the package `boxers` in your jsp page like `<%@ page import="boxers" %>` then you can access the class without specifying the package

Comment: `boxers.B cannot be resolved to a type` is like searchnig for a class named `boxers` and within it a property called B

Comment: @El Sam I can't import only boxers - netbeans requires '.'. Importing `<%@ page import="boxers.*" %>` and using `B.voice()` doesn't change things..`B cannot be resolved`

Comment: Ok, import the class B `<%@ page import="boxers.B" %>` and then you can call `voice()` directly

Comment: @El Sam Netbeans highlights it - can't find the method without `B` or `boxers.B` before it..

Comment: oops, i meant `B.voice()`

Comment: @El Sam `B cannot be resolved` `An error occurred at line: 36 ` ; `36:           <p><%= B.voice()%></p>`

Comment: The problem was the `=` , it's only used when you want to print a variable, instead you want to call a method and to do it you only use the **scriptlet** , i.e `<%  someMethod();%>`

Comment: @El Sam Now, when I `<p><% B.voice();%></p>` the `<%@ page import="boxers.B" %>` usddenly causes error - `Only a type can be imported. boxers.B resolves to a package`. When I replace it with `%@ page import="boxers.*" %>` it gives an old thing: `An error occurred at line: 35 in the jsp file: /web/date_info.jsp
B cannot be resolved`, `35:           <p><% B.voice();%></p>`

Comment: you must keep the class import `<%@ page import="boxers.B" %>`, for the scriptlet , try this `<% String msg = B.voice();%> <%=msg%>`

Comment: @El Sam `An error occurred at line: 35 in the jsp file: /web/date_info.jsp
B cannot be resolved` `35:           <p><% String msg = B.voice();%></p>` and import: `An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file`  `Only a type can be imported. boxers.B resolves to a package` It sucks(

Comment: This error is really getting ridiculous,  I found a solution on SO, try this <%@ page import="boxers.B;" %> _notice the semicolon after B_

Comment: @El Sam  `HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP` remained, but there is no word about `B class` or `boxers` package, only `exception` and `root cause` things, which were present before.

PS Do you have Netbeans&Tomcat? If yes. does my initial example work for you? I begin to contemplate reinstalling everything..

Comment: In which line does the `root cause` lie ? for my java,JavaEE projects , I sue Intellij, and yes I have Tomcat. I recommend you to remove the static from the method and create an instance of you class like so `<% String msg = new B.voice();%>`

Comment: No line. Just `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Page directive: invalid value for import...` I googled it, looks like the semicolon causes it..

Tried non-static method out. It's all the same. With semicolon - gives the abovementioned exception, without - `Only a type can be imported. boxers.B resolves to a package` and `An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /web/date_info.jsp
B cannot be resolved to a type` `35:           <%!
36:               B e=new B();
37:               %>
38:               
39:           <p><% String msg = e.voice();%></p>`

Comment: this is definitely not a JSP problem, it has to do with your netbeans+tomcat ,  I recommend you delete these files, clean, create others. check this thread, it has a lot of possible answers [same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package)

Comment: @El Sam I'll check it out. Thanks for your efforts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The application wasn't deployed correctly. The deployment process, described [here](http://www.codejava.net/servers/tomcat/how-to-deploy-a-java-web-application-on-tomcat) helped me out. In particular - `copying web application archive file (.war)` and `copying unpacked web application directory`. My main mistake was that initially I applied the second method in the wrong way - copied all the folders in the app directory, created by Netbeans (build, src, web etc), while only `NetbeansProjects/app_name/build/web`'s **content** should have been copied into `tomcat/app_name/`.
Or just copy the war-file of `NebeansProjects/app_name/dist/` into `tomcat/webapps` - the tomcat will create the appropriate folder with the files himself seconds later.

tl;dr: wrong deploment, copypaste `war` or `web`'s content.