# Not able to host JSP application in a server system

Tags: java, apache, jsp, netbeans, tomcat7

I've written a JSP application using netbeans. Inside JSP page, I've used a java class to fetch the result set from Jira and the result displayed in the page. From the netbeans, am able to run the app and getting the results. Also am able to host the same app in apache running from my local machine. But when I have tried to host the same in a server machine, I've gotten the following error,

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [D:\apache-  tomcat- 7.0.33\work\Catalina\localhost\StatusReporterAPP\org\apache\jsp\web\report_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. jira.JiraFetcher resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 57 in the jsp file: /web/report.jsp
JiraFetcher cannot be resolved to a type
54:                     <!-- JAVA CODE -->
55:                     <%
56:                         String week = request.getParameter    ("weekNumber");
57:                         JiraFetcher jf = new JiraFetcher(week);
58:                         
59:             String reportType = request.getParameter ("typeofreport");
60:             if (reportType.equals ("FULL_TEAM"))
```

In short, the app is running fine in the local apache tomcat server and in netbeans, But when I tried to host it in a remote machine, am getting the above error.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was due to the inappropriate folder structure.
Instead of the complete project folder, I've added the war file into webapps folder of the apache tomcat server, then the web server automatically parses the war and create the proper folder. Then I am able to host the application in remote machine and its working fine now.