# Importing own java files in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I'm kind of a JSP noob (and I'm forced to write old school because of school) and I have this pure java file that I wrote. I want to use that `FooBar.java` file and the class inside it (`packagename.name.FooBar`) inside my `.jsp` files. My questions are:

- Where should I place my `.java` files? Some places told me to put them in `/src` and some told me to put them in `/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes`. Both of these don't work.
- How can I import them correctly? I'm trying `<%@ page import = "packagename.name.*" %>` and it doesn't work in both cases above (when the package is in `src` or in `classes`.

**EDIT:** Now I've tried compiling them and putting them in `WEB-INF/classes/packagename/name`, but I still get errors:

```
Only a type can be imported. packagename.name.FooBar resolves to a package
```

And then of course these (because it didn't import correctly): `FooBar cannot be resolved to a type`.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Thank you everyone! If you're wondering, here's what solved my problem:

- As @user7294900 mentioned, you can only import `.class` files and not `.java` files. Use the `javac` command to compile files - [here's more information](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html).
- If you get the `resolves to a package` error ensure that the files are in the right place, for example if you have `C` class in package `a.b` you need the `C.class` file to be in `WEB-INF/classes/a/b/C.class`. If it is, try simply restarting your IDE/server.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp) is how to import the classes. Regarding the location, you can put it in `src` folder, they will be compiled and put into `classes`.

Comment: @DarshanMehta how exactly and when do they get compiled into `classes` from `src`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP file can import files with class extension and not java extension.

Class file is a compiled java file.

You need to compile you java file which will create FooBar.class

One option is to save FooBar.class file in a jar under /WEB-INF/lib

Second option is save FooBar.class inside your classes folder under relevant pack for example if your package is a.b /WEB-INF/classes/a/b/FooBar.class

Comment: Okay, thank you. I tried compiling the files but I still get an error: `Only a type can be imported. package.name.FooBar resolves to a package`

Comment: Probably foobar.class in foobar folder which shouldnt be

Comment: no, look at the original post - it's in `WEB-INF/classes/packagename/name`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package

Comment: That actually wasn't the problem but I managed to solve it by simply restarting the IDE. Thank you!