# JasperException in JSP

Tags: java, maven, jsp, intellij-idea, gson

I am getting Jasper Exception whenever I import gson library . Any idea what is wrong?

```
<%@ page import="com.google.gson.Gson" %>                            
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
     pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>  
                              
    <%String jsonString = request.getParameter("user");
Gson gson = new Gson();
object gigObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, object.class);%>
```

Pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably it should be import="com.google.**code**.gson.Gson".

I.e. dependency and import packages don't match.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [another similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27825848/2000323):

> If you spell the class name wrong or the class isn't on the classpath, the JSP processor will say it "resolves to a package" rather than that it doesn't exist.

So make sure you have the Gson library in the Tomcat classpath: i.e. if you deploy it via IntelliJ IDEA's [artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html) make sure the library is included into the artifact.