# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to run simple code to connect with mysql. I m using eclipse and tomcat.
I have added mysql-connector-java-8.0.1.9.jar in Libraries:

Libraries-->mysql-->mysql-connector-java-8.0.1.9.jar

I have been at it for several hours adding and removing mysql-connector-java-8.0.1.9.jar to build path cannot get it running. Please help. Do I need to add any thing in run configuration??

This is the error on eclipse browser:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:599)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:500)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



Root Cause 
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:917)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:846)
    org.apache.jsp.regCheck_jsp._jspService(regCheck_jsp.java:129)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



Root Cause 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver
    compute.DB.con(DB.java:21)
    org.apache.jsp.regCheck_jsp._jspService(regCheck_jsp.java:100)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



Root Cause 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1951)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1794)
    compute.DB.con(DB.java:21)
    org.apache.jsp.regCheck_jsp._jspService(regCheck_jsp.java:100)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

This is the output in console:

```
> Mar 16, 2020 4:57:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Mysql] has started
Mar 16, 2020 4:57:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/Mysql] is completed
Mar 16, 2020 4:57:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Mysql] threw exception [javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1951)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1794)
    at compute.DB.con(DB.java:21)
    at org.apache.jsp.regCheck_jsp._jspService(regCheck_jsp.java:100)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1195)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:654)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:319)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Try - 05 Trying to establish con in regCheck.jsp
Con method called Try 5A
Try 05a - Trying to connect
```

This is DB.java:

```
package compute;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.*;

public class DB {


    final static String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new";
    final static String USER = "admin";
    final static String PASS = "admin";

    public static Connection con() {
        System.out.println("Con method called Try 5A");
        Connection con;
        try {
            System.out.println("Try 05a - Trying to connect");
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            System.out.println("Try 05a- con established ");
            return con;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static Statement st() {
        Statement stmt;
        try {
            stmt=DB.con().createStatement();
            return null;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is regCheck.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@page import="compute.DB" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        String user = request.getParameter("username");
        System.out.println("Try - 05 Trying to establish con in regCheck.jsp");
        Connection con = DB.con();
        System.out.println("Preparing Statement in regCheck.jsp");
        PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement("Insert into register(username)values(?)");

        p.setString(1,user);
        System.out.println("user::" +user);

        int R = p.executeUpdate();
        if(R!=0)
            response.sendRedirect("index.html");
        else
            response.sendRedirect("register.jsp");

        %>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: No I am not using maven.

Comment: Have you set the jar file to deploy with your app in the Deployment Assembly property page?

Comment: No, I don't have any idea about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar  to Tomcat 7.0/Lib and now it's working find. 
I removed it from Library and everywhere and it works.
I created new project with the same code and without adding mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar to any library or build path, it's running fine. 
I found the instruction to add to tomcat somewhere on youtube.

Comment: When i made new project, i faced :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package situation, i had to make new package with another name then i got it to work. I do not understand why this kind of things happen, isn't code supposed to run same everytime?

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC driver library is missing from your *runtime* CLASSPATH i.e. the CLASSPATH where Tomcat looks for the required classes in order to execute your compiled code.