# Java Error : Only a type can be imported resolves to a package

Tags: java, jsp, jena, ontology

I get the error: "Only a type can be imported.
Someone has explained the cause here but I am not sure what I supposed to do to fix this. FYI: I am using Eclipse. I have added the code that does the importing below.

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.jena.query.Query"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jena.query.QuerySolution"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Literal"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.jena.util.FileManager"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.IOException"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
```

**Edit: the actual error is below:**

```
An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Welcome\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\myWebApp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.jena.query.Query resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [16] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Welcome\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\myWebApp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [17] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Welcome\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\myWebApp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [18] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Welcome\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\myWebApp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [19] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Welcome\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\myWebApp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.jena.query.QuerySolution resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [20] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Welcome\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\myWebApp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [21] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Welcome\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\myWebApp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [22] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Welcome\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\myWebApp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Literal resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [23] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Welcome\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\myWebApp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [24] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Welcome\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\myWebApp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [25] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Welcome\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\myWebApp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [26] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Welcome\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\myWebApp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [27] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\Welcome\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\myWebApp\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.apache.jena.util.FileManager resolves to a package
```

Comment: someone help me

Comment: It might be that the Jena jars is not on the classpath of the JSP at runtime. That would explain why the last two (java.io...) do not give an error.

Comment: Hey Andys How can I contact you? I need your help

Comment: I don't use JSP. Search StackOverflow e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858463/java-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-xyz-resolves-to-a-package

Comment: Please add index_jsp.java to the question so the lines with errors are visible.