# Only a type can be imported. net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaImpl resolves to a package

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, recaptcha

I am building a test application for learning purpose. I have implemented google recaptcha v2 at my signup page. while writing captcha validation at back end, I am getting the following error:

> Only a type can be imported. net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaImpl resolves to a package

Let me tell you what scenarios I have tried.

1. Added recaptcha4j-0.0.7.jar to the Referenced Libraries path. The jar file has `net.tanesha.recaptcha` package which has `ReCaptchaImpl.class`
2. Tried adding semicolumn at the end of import statement

```
  <%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaImpl" %>
  <%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaResponse;" %>
```

but issue still persists.

This is the code that i have written for importing the package from jar file.

```
<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaImpl" %>
<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaResponse" %>
```

I am new to java web development. Any insights or inputs would be very much helpful to me. I am using jsp as my backend.

Comment: Where else did you use the string `ReCaptchaImpl`? Do you have a file or a folder named `ReCaptchaImpl`? Randomly adding a character like a semicolon somewhere is not the solution, but might be the cause of your problem (avoid trial and error and read the documentation when in doubt): please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to import `RecaptchaImpl` class, but instead you can import an interface that this class implements.

```
<%@ page import="net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptcha" %>
```

---

You have got the error:

> Only a type can be imported. net.tanesha.recaptcha.ReCaptchaImpl resolves to a package

It is because you use a semicolon `;` at the end of the class name. This problem well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1858635/573032).

> The semicolon causes a syntax error, but triggers a recheck in Eclipse, some how after deleting the semicolon then the import is back to normal without the wiggly under line red, weird but works!