# What are the possible causes of JasperException

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a JSP that takes an `Arraylist` from the session object and removes the items from it. It seemed to be working fine and then out of nowhere when I navigate to that page, the page is blank. I checked the Tomcat log files and in catalina.out I am receiving a `JasperException` an it is showing it as being on a line with the following

```
for(int i; i < agentItems.size(); i++)
```

`agentItems` is the name of the `ArrayList` I am using. I have been debugging it and can't seem to figure out what the problem might be. I have read that a `JasperException` is sometiems thrown as a JSP's `NullPointerException`. Is this true or am I just completely overlooking the problem?

I have the web application running on a local machine and a intermediate server for development in which both of them have had no trouble. Why could it be that only on this server it is giving me problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can be *everything*. You need to look a bit further in the stacktrace, peek to the `caused by` or `root cause` part and the trace which comes thereafter. It can be caused by many things. The JSP basically get compiled into one large `try` block and any catched [`Throwable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) will be wrapped into a servletcontainer specific exception like `JasperException` in Tomcat and clones. It boils down to this:

```
try {
    // All translated JSP code comes here. Max 64K.
} catch (Throwable t) {
    throw new JasperException(t);
}
```

Check the `.java` filename in the 1st line of the stacktrace, locate this in the `work` directory of the servletcontainer and open the file in an editor. Do you see it?

That said, using *scriptlets* is a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831238/jsp-for-business-layer/1832327#1832327). Use Servlets to control/preprocess/postprocess requests, use Javabeans to represent data models, use Taglibs in JSP to control the page flow and output, use Expression Language (EL) in JSP to access backend data. In your specific case, you can loop over an array or `List` using JSTL's `c:forEach` tag.

```
<c:forEach items="${agents}" var="agent">
    <p>Agent: ${agent.name}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

`jasperexception` can also occur when JSP is not able to access  an element or item it's obtaining from outside and here it maybe is unable to access `agentItems`. Try to provide fully qualified class name or import the package otherwise.