# JSP: I am doing an application in which i have to download ppt file 

Tags: java, jsp

I am working on an application wherein I have to download a PPT file using a JSP page. I am using the following code, but it's not working.

```
<% try {
   String filename = "file/abc.ppt";

   // set the http content type to "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM
   response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");

   // initialize the http content-disposition header to
   // indicate a file attachment with the default filename
   // "myFile.txt"
   String disHeader = "Attachment Filename=\"abc.ppt\"";

   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);

   // transfer the file byte-by-byte to the response object
   File fileToDownload = new File(filename);
   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new
      FileInputStream(fileToDownload);
   int i;
   while ((i=fileInputStream.read())!=-1)
   {
      out.write(i);
   }
   fileInputStream.close();
   out.close();
   }catch(Exception e) // file IO errors
   {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

Can anybody solve this problem?

Comment: Check the file actually exists before you download it, just dump out to standard out file.exists()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only the `Content-Disposition` header is incorrect, but you're incorrectly using JSP instead of a Servlet for this particular task.

JSP is a view technology. Everything outside the scriptlets `<% %>` will be **printed** to the response, including whitespace characters such as newlines. It would surely corrupt binary files.

You could trim the whitespace in the JSP file, but scriptlets are discouraged since a decade and nowadays considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831238/jsp-for-business-layer/1832327#1832327). Raw Java code belongs in Java classes, not in JSP files. The real solution is to use a `HttpServlet` for this.

Create a class which `extends HttpServlet`, implement the `doGet()` method, move the Java code from the JSP file into this method, map this servlet on a certain `url-pattern` and your problem should disappear. You can find [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html) a *basic* example of such a servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top there should be a semicolon in the Content-Disposition header ("attachment*;* filename ...)

You should also probably do a response.reset() before starting to set headers and stream.  Internet Explorer has really strange rules about streaming files from secure sockets and won't work right if you don't clear the caching headers.